# How do I serialize complex POD using streams?

Tags: c++, serialization, c++17

I need to compose binary messages to send over a serial port. I have been using a union of structs to make these messages as I would in C:

```
union {
  struct {
    uint32_t d1;
    uint8_t d2;
  } packet;
  std::array<uint8_t, 100> serial_data;
} Buffer;

Buffer buffer;
buffer.packet.d1 = 42;
buffer.packet.d2 = 17;
write(fd, buffer.serial_data.data(), sizeof(buffer.packet));
```

How do I use streams to compose binary data packets for network traffic over a serial port? The examples I have seen all use text based data, and I need binary (packed complex POD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `union` at all. And I believe that type-punning through unions, while permitted in C, is undefined behavior in C++. For (un)serialization, you can just cast the structure to characters. Note that only casting to either `char`, `unsigned char` or `std::byte` allows us to avoid undefined behavior that would result from the strict aliasing rule violation if we would cast to some other type. Check the following example.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct Packet
{
    std::uint32_t value1;
    std::uint8_t  value2;
};

int main()
{
    const Packet source{ 123456U, 123U };
    try
    {
        std::ofstream fout{ "data.bin", std::ios::binary };
        fout.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit | std::ios_base::badbit);
        fout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&source), sizeof source);
    }
    catch (const std::ios_base::failure& err)
    {
        std::cerr << "Serialization failed, caught " << err.what() << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << "Serialized:\t" << source.value1
        << ", " << static_cast<unsigned>(source.value2) << '\n';

    Packet dest{};
    try
    {
        std::ifstream fin{ "data.bin", std::ios::binary };
        fin.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit | std::ios_base::badbit);
        fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dest), sizeof dest);
    }
    catch (const std::ios_base::failure& err)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unserialization failed, caught " << err.what() << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << "Unserialized:\t" << dest.value1
        << ", " << static_cast<unsigned>(dest.value2) << '\n';

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```